# How can i use variables dynamically by changing their names using code

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, sqlplus

Want a way to refer different variables by changing their names dynamically in a plsql block.

Tried with simple loops which will change effective names of the variables.
Writing a cascaded plsql block using statement but due to size of existing code it is of no use.

```
set serveroutput on;
declare
foo1 number:=111;
foo2 number:=222;
begin
execute immediate 'dbms_output.put_line(foo'||'1)';
for i in 0..2
loop
dbms_output.put_line(foo||i);
end loop;
end;
/
```

expected output to be 111
output is error as below
Error report -
ORA-00900: invalid SQL statement
ORA-06512: at line 5
00900. 00000 -  "invalid SQL statement"

Comment: *"Want a way to refer different variables by changing their names dynamically in a plsql block"* This is not how PL/SQL works. So please explain what **business problem** you are trying to solve and we can provide the appropriate solution.

Answer (score 4):

Your variables are local. The DBMS_OUTPUT package doesn't know them. So the resulting string `dbms_output.put_line(foo1)` can not be executed with `execute immediate`.

The typical way to solve this is to use an array of values rather than separate variables:

```
declare
  type t_array is varray(2) of integer;
  v_array t_array := t_array(111, 222);
begin
  for i in 1..2 loop
    dbms_output.put_line(v_array(i));
  end loop;
end;
```

The same with a dynamic array:

```
declare
  type t_array is table of integer;
  v_array t_array := t_array();
begin
  v_array.extend(1);
  v_array(1) := 111;
  v_array.extend(1);
  v_array(2) := 222;
  for i in 1 .. v_array.count loop
    dbms_output.put_line(v_array(i));
  end loop;
end;
```

Comment: Thank you Thorsten for the solution but can we have dynamic array instead of static varray(2)?

Comment: Yes, of course. I've updated my answer accordingly.

Answer (score 2):

Let's take it one step at a time. First, static code that works:

```
SQL> declare
  2  foo1 number:=111;
  3  foo2 number:=222;
  4  begin
  5  dbms_output.put_line(foo1);
  6  end;
  7  /

111
```

Now, if you want to EXECUTE IMMEDIATE some text, you have to put **all the code** in the text:

```
SQL> declare
  2    l_code_block varchar2(4000) := '
  3  declare
  4  foo1 number:=111;
  5  foo2 number:=222;
  6  begin
  7  dbms_output.put_line(foo2);
  8  end;
  9  ';
 10  begin
 11  execute immediate l_code_block;
 12  end;
 13  /

222
```

Next step: if we want to change a **value** dynamically, we can and should use a "bind variable".

```
SQL> declare
  2    l_code_block varchar2(4000) := '
  3  declare
  4  foo1 number:=111;
  5  foo2 number:=222;
  6  begin
  7  dbms_output.put_line(:n);
  8  end;
  9  ';
 10  begin
 11  execute immediate l_code_block using 1;
 12  end;
 13  /

1
```

But if we try to use a bind variable to change the **code**, it doesn't work.

```
SQL> declare
  2    l_code_block varchar2(4000) := '
  3  declare
  4  foo1 number:=111;
  5  foo2 number:=222;
  6  begin
  7  dbms_output.put_line(foo:n);
  8  end;
  9  ';
 10  begin
 11  execute immediate l_code_block using 1;
 12  end;
 13  /

...
Error report -
ORA-06550: line 6, column 25:
PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "" when expecting one of the following
...
```

So if we want to change the **code** dynamically, we have to do a REPLACE on the text.

```
SQL> declare
  2    l_code_block varchar2(4000) := '
  3  declare
  4  foo1 number:=111;
  5  foo2 number:=222;
  6  begin
  7  dbms_output.put_line(foo#N#);
  8  end;
  9  ';
 10  begin
 11  execute immediate replace(l_code_block,'#N#',1);
 12  end;
 13  /

111
```

Finally, here is your loop:

```
SQL> declare
  2    l_code_block varchar2(4000) := '
  3  declare
  4  foo1 number:=111;
  5  foo2 number:=222;
  6  begin
  7  dbms_output.put_line(foo#N#);
  8  end;
  9  ';
 10  begin
 11    for i in 1..2 loop
 12      execute immediate replace(l_code_block,'#N#',i);
 13    end loop;
 14  end;
 15  /

111
222
```

Please understand, I am trying to answer your question as asked. This "dynamic" approach should be avoided whenever possible, and it is almost always possible. We would have to back up to the business requirement in order to recommend the most appropriate technique.

Best regards,
Stew Ashton

Comment: great description of how to use dynamic pl/sql to turn a simple 6 line block into a more than double the size nightmare.

Comment: Thank You Stew, i tried this one but my plsql block is very large. Is there any way without having to store query in a variable?

Comment: I thought I answered this already. The answer is no. Is there any way to convince you to give up and try another approach?